# Add new resolution with xrandr on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, display, wayland

My laptop has a resolution of 1920x1080 but I can't find it in `Setting --> Devices --> Displays` (nor any other 16:9 resolution), so I tried to add it using `xrandr`. Unfortunately when I try to add it I get an error "No protocol specified Can't open display :0"

> : `xrandr`
>   Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3440 x 1440, maximum 8192 x 8192
>   XWAYLAND0 connected 3440x1440+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
>      3440x1440     59.94*+
>   : `sudo cvt 1920 1080 60`
>   1920x1080 59.96 Hz (CVT 2.07M9) hsync: 67.16 kHz; pclk: 173.00 MHz
>   Modeline
>   "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync
>   : `sudo xrandr --newmode "1920x1080_60.00"  173.00  1920 2048 2248 2576  1080 1083 1088 1120 -hsync +vsync`
>   No protocol specified
>   Can't open display :0

What can I try?